# How to open a password protected PDF using VB6/VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, vb6, password-encryption

I want to **open** and **view** a **password protected PDF** file in **VB6/VB.NET** program. I have tried using the Acrobat PDF Library but could not do it.

The reason I want to create a password protected PDF file is because I dont want the PDF file to be opened without the password externally i.e outside the program.

Comment: *open a password protected PDF file from VB6/VB.NET* - open it for... **what**? Open in a viewer component? Open to manipulate it?

Comment: For viewing in a viewer component without asking the password but only from the program and when opened outside it should ask for the password!

Comment: Then you had better add that information to your question. Dandy's answer for example merely targeted at removing a password automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the information.

Answer (score 0):

To open a password protected PDF you will need to develop at least a PDF parser, decryptor and generator. I wouldn't recommend to do that, though. It's nowhere near an easy task to accomplish.

With help of a PDF library everything is much simpler. You might want to try Docotic.Pdf library for the task.

Here is a sample for you task:

```
public static void unprotectPdf(string input, string output)
{
    bool passwordProtected = PdfDocument.IsPasswordProtected(input);
    if (passwordProtected)
    {
        string password = null; // retrieve the password somehow

        using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(input, password))
        {
            // clear both passwords in order
            // to produce unprotected document
            doc.OwnerPassword = "";
            doc.UserPassword = "";

            doc.Save(output);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // no decryption is required
        File.Copy(input, output, true);
    }
}
```

Docotic.Pdf can also extract text (formatted or not) from PDFs. It might be useful for indexing (I guess it's what you are up to because you mentioned Adobe IFilter)

you can convert code to vb over the internet

Comment: Is the Docotic.PDF Library free?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373926/lightweight-open-source-pdf-library-in-c

Comment: I will try using PDFSharp, but is there a translated (VB.NET) version available?

Comment: PDFSharp works fine from VB.Net, we use it. 99.9% of the time you can call a C# library from VB.Net very very easily with no problems at all.